# Voice activated recording software for Windows

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

I'm looking for a voice recording software that would be voice activated. The program should be running in background at all times and when it detects volume from microphone input, it should start to record. And when there has been silence from microphone for some time, the recording should be stopped and saved in file.

I remember using such program in Windows XP, but I cannot recall the name. I have found software called "Snooper", but that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a program that is free but with ads, Snooper gives only 30 days trial which is not suitable. Any help would be appreciated.